# Springboot - can't understand why

Tags: spring-boot

[image: thats what I get]

I try catch the error but cant understand how fix it .

Answer (score 0):

The error code 400 that you're getting from using the API is telling you that you've provided some incorrect data. To find out what you're doing wrong, you should drop your break-point on the print statement in the `catch` block or narrow down your exception to [HttpClientErrorException](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.3.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/HttpClientErrorException.html) instead of `Throwable` which allows you to check the response body.

Another thing to look out is that you are giving the `RestTemplate` an already encoded URL `id%2Cname`, which will result in double encoding, since  `RestTemplate` does the encoding for you.